# What happens when i call a sub vba

Tags: vba, excel-2010, call

I'm using the Call Function to activate other Macro's, but I'm not entirly sure how VB reads this function.
(I'm using this with MS Excel 2010)

For Example:

```
Sub main macro ()

blabla
blabla

Call Edit
Call Save
Call HistoryLog

End Sub
```

This code has some If funcions, and at some point will get to "Call Edit"
Here the Macro "Sub Edit()"will be activated. But I need this code to edit data, save the data into a new file and make a history log in an other Excel sheet.

If VBA is finished with the "Sub Edit()" part how will the code continu?
Does it Calls the "Sub Save()" part?
Or do I realy require to type "Call Sub Save" at the end of the "Sub Edit()" part?

Answer (score 1):

VBA will process all lines of your code in the order they are given, unless an error occurs in one of them. As it is, your code will just stop at the point of error.

Where to call `Save()` really depends on how you want your code to work. If you want to make sure that after *every* call to `Edit()` changes are saved, I'd call `Save()` within `Edit()`. If sometimes you want to call `Edit()` without calling `Save()` you should not put the call to `Save()` into `Edit()`.

Comment: oke, And what will happen when I use the code mentioned above? 1. Sub Edit is Called, 2 Sub Edit is finished 3.? Wil it start to run Save? or wil it continu with the first sub below it. (ignoring "Call Save" and "Call HistoryLog" because the code is jumped to Sub Edit  so will never read Call Save and Call HistoryLog) ? thanks in advance

Comment: You are pretty new to programming, aren't you? The subs in your macro are *not* being executed unless you call them. If you remove all the `call` lines from `sub main macro()` you will notice that nothing is happening. Only the subs that you are actually calling directly or indirectly from the main sub get executed. Execution stops when the main sub is done or an error occurs that causes the main sub to be ended prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a procedure from within another procedure, program control returns to the line just below the `Call` line. In your example, when the `Edit` procedure reaches an `End Sub` or `Exit Sub` line, program control will continue on the `Call Save` line (the line just below `Call Edit`).

The `Call` keyword is included in the language for backward compatitbility. You can call the Edit procedure like

```
Edit
```

without the `Call` keyword. If you like using `Call`, it doesn't harm anything though.